# Moderator on another site removes B"H from question. Is this acceptable?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Here's the [question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/what-is-the-goal-of-veganism). The moderator edited out B"H from the body of a user's question. He made a snarky comment about the site not being religious, and I commented a couple of times explaining what it meant and asked him to change it back.  He deletes the comments. He also seems upset because I recently asked a question about veganism and religion and I think he's taking it out on this user.

Is it acceptable for a moderator to remove this from a question or is this a form of religious discrimination? There are only 3 moderators on vegetarianism.se site, and this was done by the most active moderator.

There are a couple of [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283889/is-salaamun-alekum-in-a-question-religious-content) [mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137066/religious-salutations-in-religious-se-sites) concerning "religious salutations" but this feels wrong.

I'd like to get another opinion on this to determine if it's acceptable or should be escalated.

Comment: Downvoted? Why? It's a wonder new people ask a question at all.

Comment: Paul, please take a look at "Voting is different on Meta." https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely acceptable. This has nothing to do with religion and everything to do with how the SE sites work. We regularly remove "Hello" and "thanks", we remove anything that isn't directly related to the question and necessary for the question to be understood. The fact that it is a religious salutation doesn't seem relevant at all. It's a salutation, and salutations are regularly removed from all sites of the network. Here's the relevant Meta SE post:

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/203101)

There is very strong community consensus to remove such things and it has been standard practice across the network for many years. it isn't about religion, it's about keeping posts streamlined and to the point and free of anything not necessary to understand the question/answer.

Comment: Well, it's not a salutation (but rather an acknowledgement that one's ability to write, or ability to write this content, is God-given), but the reason to remove salutations applies to it also.  FWIW, IIRC I've removed "B"H" from atop MY posts, too.

Comment: @msh210 This helps. It would have been more helpful if the original mod had just explained it like this. I appreciate the feedback.